# laravel 5.5 get the object id inside transaction

Tags: laravel-5.5

I want to use database transaction but use the created id within the transaction.

```
DB::transaction(function () { 
     $user = User::insert($save_data);// this return bool
     $user = User::insertGetId($save_data); // this returns nothing
})
```

Laravel 5.5.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean `this returns nothing`? it should returns `int` value or throw error. If you add `dd($user)` in the end of transaction what it returns?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last inserted id by:

```
DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();

// insert a user and get the record it
DB::transaction(function () { 
    $user = User::insert($save_data);
    $lastID = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the `insertGetId` method:

```
DB::transaction(function () { 
    $id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId($save_data);
});
```

Using Eloquent will return the id, as well:

```
DB::transaction(function () { 
    // using create
    $user = User::create($save_data);
    // $user->id

    // or using save
    $user = new User;
    $user->foo = $save_data['foo'];
    $user->save();
    // $user->id;
});
```